# Superpotential Symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, supersymmetry, noethers-theorem

Superpotential in general has the form $W=a_n\Phi^n$. If I require that my superpotential should be invariant under the following global transformation,

$\delta \Phi=i\epsilon \Phi$  and  $\delta \Phi^*=-i\epsilon \Phi^*$

What form should the superpotential have as the original form seems not to have this symmetry because

$\delta W = \partial W/ \partial \Phi \times \delta \Phi $ which is not 0.

Thanks

Comment: What about imposing $\delta W= 0$ and looking at what constraints that yields doesn't work? Also, is that transformation supposed to be infinitesimal, i.e. is its finite version $\Phi\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\Phi$? Is $\Phi$ a complex or a real field? This needs more context, and you should show a little more of your own thinking about this.

Comment: $\Phi$ is a chiral Superfield which is complex, $$ \delta W = a_n \Phi^{n-1} \delta \Phi =i\epsilon a_n \Phi^{n}  $$ which is not zero. Thats my doubt. I think all the details were written in the original post. The transformation rules are written and only the transformation of W needs to be checked which is the question. There is no work to show, all work has been shown!!!

Comment: Well, if that is the transformation behaviour, it is obvious that only $a_n = 0\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ gives you an invariant potential. However, might it be that the even powers $\Phi^{2n}$ can be replaced by $\lvert \Phi \rvert^{2n}$, which would be invariant?

Comment: Superpotential by definition is only a function of $\Phi$ and not $\Phi^*$. Naively I thought a should be 0 as well but I came across Weinberg Vol 3 Chp 26 the line above equation(26.6.17). It says " The superpotential is invariant under the transformation that i wrote". I was just wondering if there was any other form of Superpotential that might make it invariant because given the usual choice it has to be 0.

Comment: The information in that comment is *exactly* the "context" I was talking about in my first. Saying you *see* that it should be just zero, but that Weinberg says it isn't is a far better question than just asking us without context about this.